# Is it possible to make HTTP calls to applications outside of Azure from a web API running in Azure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, http, vpn

Is it possible to make **HTTP** calls to applications outside of **Azure** from a web API running in Azure?

I'm trying to connect a ASP.NET web API in Azure to a wpf application that runs on a PC at my company. Both the applications request data from each other using *HTTP calls with JSON*. This works fine locally because i can use localhost but

> when running the web API in Azure the web API can't reach the wpf application

I have looked into *Azure Point-to-Site and Site-to-Site* connections but most examples that i found show connection with a VM in Azure and nothing about web API's.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you authenticating communication in your wpf application? What is the protocol? Is there a firewall? Typically wpf applications will talk to web applications first to establish a connection not the other way around.

Comment: Right now a Google Home makes a call to the web API. The WPF application is used to display information based on the trigger from the Google Home using a HTTPListener.

These calls are made, the info is shown and thats all it does. To make the calls I use a .NET HTTP Client object and HTTPResponseMessage objects.

Comment: I really see no reason why you azure web api can't call out to any http address. I think it'll be based on the url of your wpf app. If it's an ip address that will have to be your external ip address rather than your local network IP address.

Comment: check your external IP address with this https://www.myexternalip.com/

Comment: I've tried this but the web API just stops responding when using the public IP. My guess would be that the firewall is blocking this but that's is why i looked into using a VPN to bypass this issue.

I have not found a way to get crash info the web API once i've published it to Azure so i can't give you the detailed info sadly.

Comment: Just so I understand, the web API stops responding when you direct it to send messages to a url using your public IP address?

Comment: The web API does not send a message to the wpf application when changing to the public IP. I also tested it with postman and when calling the api it returns:  "Message": "An error has occurred." after a while.

I can call the web API again but it just returns the same message.

Comment: not very useful errors :( But you need to be able to talk to the public ip address or a public url which will require a domain registration. The other way to go about this is to have your wpf application register for callbacks to your service using signalR. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't get your scenario even after reading all the comments, however here's a shot in the dark.

First of all, no, there are no restrictions as to what destination you may call from Azure, yes that includes the dark web, although not necessarily a recommended destination for both traffic and tourism alike.

For the second part, if what you're calling is behind a firewall and your API runs in Azure App Service, take a look at [Hybrid Connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections), it's built as a solution to that exact scenario, no IPsec or firewall rules are in play. The connectivity from on-prem will be outbound.

[image: Azure App Service Hybrid Connections]

Comment: Sorry for the unclear explanations but your shot in the dark helped me a lot. It allowed me to communicate through my company's firewall to my WPF app.